# Find records if there are other values in other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I store translations in a table. I would like to find out every record for which I have a translation. The records differ only in their language code column. The other primary keys are all the same. I would also like to find out for which I have no translation yet.

**Example records**:

```
Id  SudId   LanguageCode    Caption
1   0       en-us           hello
1   0       fr-fr           bonjour
2   1       en-us           how are you?
2   1       fr-fr           comment allez-vous?
3   0       en-us           how is the weather?
```

In the first step I would expect only the first and the third dataset, because I have a translation for this one.

```
Id  SudId   LanguageCode    Caption
1   0       en-us           hello
2   1       en-us           how are you?
```

Then I would like to find all for which there is no translation. Here I expect the last record.

```
Id  SudId   LanguageCode    Caption
3   0       en-us           how is the weather?
```

Comment: What is your DBMS? Oracle? Or MySQL? Or SQL Server? ... Please tag your request with it. Then, what have you tried? Where are you stuck? Do you have some query you can show us?

Comment: You can try GROUP BY  id  HAVING Count(*)=1 for second output

Comment: Is this about only one or at least two languages in the table for a sudid? Or a particular language? Is it about en-us and another / no other? Or about fr-fr entry existing or not?

Comment: On a side note: An ID should uniquely identify the table's rows. There should be no duplicates, as is the case for 1 and 2 in your example. Are these just typos?

Comment: If the translation is done only in fr-fr then you can use ROW_Number order by Languagecode and select 1st row

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using correlated subquery -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=67af5d86884e8a6fa5df3bafb788e7f3)**

```
select * from tablename a where not exists 
  (select 1 from tablename b where a.id=b.id and languagecode in ('en-us','fr-fr') 
     group by id having count(distinct LanguageCode)=2)
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  sudid   LanguageCode    caption
3   0       en-us           how is the weather?
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using LEFT JOIN**:

Find records where a translation exists:

```
select distinct m.Id, m.SudId, m.LanguageCode, m.Caption
from mytable m
left join mytable o 
   on o.id = m.id 
      and o.sudid = m.sudid 
      and o.languagecode <> m.languagecode
where m.languagecode = 'en-us'
and o.id is not null
```

Find records where a translation does not exist:

```
select distinct m.Id, m.SudId, m.LanguageCode, m.Caption
from mytable m
left join mytable o 
   on o.id = m.id 
      and o.sudid = m.sudid 
      and o.languagecode <> m.languagecode
where m.languagecode = 'en-us'
and o.id is null
```

**Using EXISTS/NOT EXISTS**:

Find records where a translation exists:

```
select m.Id, m.SudId, m.LanguageCode, m.Caption
from mytable m
where m.languagecode = 'en-us'
and exists (
   select 1 
   from mytable o
   where o.id = m.id
   and o.sudid = m.sudid
   and o.languagecode <> m.languagecode
)
```

Find records where a translation does not exist:

```
select m.Id, m.SudId, m.LanguageCode, m.Caption
from mytable m
where m.languagecode = 'en-us'
and not exists (
   select 1 
   from mytable o
   where o.id = m.id
   and o.sudid = m.sudid
   and o.languagecode <> m.languagecode
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**With group by**

Complete

```
select Id, SudId, STRING_AGG(LanguageCode + ': ' + caption, ', ') as Translations from t 
group by Id, SudId
Having count(*) = 2
```

Missing

```
select Id, SudId, STRING_AGG(LanguageCode + ': ' + caption, ', ') as Translations from t 
group by Id, SudId
Having count(*) <> 2
```

Both

```
select Id, SudId, STRING_AGG(LanguageCode + ': ' + caption, ', ') as Translations,
       CASE WHEN count(*) = 2 Then 1 else 0 end as TranslationComplete
from t 
group by Id, SudId
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7854793890b66e9179352d855a485b1d)